# python checking noee makes exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I have this code

```
 if response.meta['nextPage'] is None:
```

and I got this exception:

```
    if response.meta['nextPage'] is None:
exceptions.KeyError: 'nextPage'
```

I know that response.meta doesn't have nextPage, I am just checking

what is that error please?

I am using scrapy with python

Comment: There is no item in the dict with the key 'nextPaxe', then you get the key error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `get` method of dictionaries:

```
if response.meta.get('nextPage') is None:
    ...
```

Comment: many thanks yes it works, +1, will accept when the system allows